# Listview Groups. Group pictures under a title by Date Taken

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, grouping

So I currently have a ListView which displays a collection of photos in it.
I would like to be able to now group these photos by the Date they were taken. I have the date taken property available to me on my "Photo" object. But I am unsure of how to group the photos. I don't really want the groups to be Expandable/Collapsable.

So far I have:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredPhotoFiles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhotoVM.SelectedPhoto}">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}}"
                            ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                            MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                            ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="2,4,2,4">
                            <Grid.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray" Opacity="0.5"/>
                            </Grid.Background>
                            <Image Source="{Binding PhotoFileInfo.FullName}" Width="300" Height="170" />                              
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

where FilteredPhotos is a List ordered by DateTaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**CollectionViewSource**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx) to sort your collection on any property by adding GroupDescriptors in it.

For this first create **`CollectionViewSource`** under your resources section of window or panel whose source will bind to actual source i.e. FilteredPhotoFiles in your case. And add GroupDescriptions with propertyName set to DateTaken.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding FilteredPhotoFiles}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="DateTaken"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Second you have to set **`GroupStyle`** on ListView that how you want it to group.

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

---

Complete XAML would look like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding FilteredPhotoFiles}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="DateTaken"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhotoVM.SelectedPhoto}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}}"
                    ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                    MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                    ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="2,4,2,4">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray" Opacity="0.5"/>
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <Image Source="{Binding PhotoFileInfo.FullName}" Width="300" Height="170" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant answer! thank you very much. My DateTaken property was a full DateTime property (minutes and seconds different for every picture) but I used a converter on the property and it worked perfectly. Thanks again!